# How do I access object property in Handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

My Ember component JS looks like below;

```
row = {};
Ember.set(row[my.constants.fieldKey], "cssType", 'leftPadding')
```

and my component HBS looks like below;

```
{{my-field cssType=(get row (concat (my-field-key 'SECTION_ID' 'FIELD_ID') '.cssType'))}}
```

To summarize, I only wanted to understand how can I achieve the equivalent of following JS code in hbs dynamically ?

```
row['my-field-key'].cssType
```

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly is the key you want to access from `row`?

Comment: So actually, I have row['my-field-key'].cssType ....Now 'my-field-key' is actually a dynamic value for which I have created a helper 'my-field-key' which gets the key string & works fine...But I want to access row['my-dynamic-key'].cssType

Comment: I do not think get accepts 3 params...Also "my-dynamic-key" comes from my custom helper

Answer (score 1):

Your composition of `get` and `concat` template helpers is absolutely fine. I've setup an ember-twiddle to verify that this approach is working. You could find it [here](https://ember-twiddle.com/02ec0cc744a980e3aad2885977cea3d2?numColumns=2&openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ccontrollers.application.js).

You might have an issue with your `my-field-key` template helper but it's hard to tell cause that code is missing. Also a reproduction in an ember-twiddle would be very helpfull.